# Structuring solutions with gRPC

Tags: java, architecture, grpc

I am new to the gRPC framework, I wanted to understand how I could structure my solution when using gRPC.

Basically I am planning to develop multiple business services. I would want to build a REST API which I want it to act like a client to all these services and expose endpoints to applications. The communication between the API and services will be using gRPC.

Should I structure my solution as below:

1. One project providing the gRPC stubs called `business-service-contracts`. This project contains the `.proto` files and the generated stubs.
2. One or more projects to provide the service implementation called `business-service-a`, `business-service-b`. These projects have a dependency on `business-service-contracts` and implement the generated stubs.
3. A project that implements the API called `business-api` that implements the clients for the business services and exposes them via REST API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a common reasonable approach.